# How to let users define their own page layout?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

I would like to let my users define their own layouts for their profiles within some reasonable guidelines. Imagine the controlled aesthetic of Facebook with *some* additional user flexibility. I'd like to offer these abilities:

- Define paragraphs of text with headings, bold, and bullet points (no user control over fonts, colors, sizes etc.)
- The ability to upload a couple of images per page.
- The ability to set those images anywhere in the page (left or right) in the page and have the text flow around.

How might this work? If all this data is to be stored in the database, how should I think about setting up these features?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done almost same what you describe. But using liquid (https://github.com/tobi/liquid). Its a very powerful template language and have many interesting features

and for html markup's I prefer using redcloth (http://redcloth.org/)

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 2):

You might use a HTML WYSIWTG text editor, that you can embed and it gives a graphical interface to the user to create paragraphs, list, links, images, generally anything that you could do in HTML.

I would recommend [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) if you are fine with this kind of solution. You can easily set it up according to your needs (restrict it to certain features, etc.). You can also include an image upload solution. The result will be a piece of HTML, which you can save in the database and show on the page when requested. Check the [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) and if you like it, read the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/).

**UPDATE**: You could also take a look at [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/index.php) or the [YUI Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/).

Comment: CKEditor looks awesome - expensive though!

Comment: @sscirrus: It also has open-source licensing options.